# imacros check if proxy is working

Tags: macros, bots, imacros

I have a huge imacro script to run. I added a header to connect to a proxy using a list. I'm trying to do some error handling. I need to find a way to tell imacros if the current proxy is working or not. If it's working, then continue and execute the script. If it's not working, switch to the next loop so we can start over and try with another proxy.

Here's what i have so far:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAB T=1
CLEAR
SET !FILESTOPWATCH mydata.csv
STOPWATCH ID=total

SET !DATASOURCE C:\proxies.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !TIMEOUT 60
PROXY ADDRESS={{!COL1}} BYPASS=127.0.0.1 
URL GOTO=http://www.mywebsite.com/test.php
```

The last line will connect to mywebsite.com and display the page test.php which is just a blank page with the word "working". If we can see the word "working" befiore the 60 seconds timeout, then we can continue with the rest of the script. But if we couldn't get the "working" word before 60 seconds, i need to exit current loop and switch to next, and this is what i can't figure out how to do

Comment: 'iMacros' itself (i.e. iim-code) doesn't allow you using 'if'-clauses. For this purpose you should apply certain Scripting Interface, e.g. the JavaScript Scripting Interface for Firefox browser.

Comment: any example please ? i have no idea how to mix javascript or how to use it for my situation. imacros have a function to locate a tag on a page, i could use it to detect if the word "working" is found, but i have no idea what to do next http://wiki.imacros.net/Web_Testing#Keyword_Search_with_TAG

Answer (score 1):

First of all try this script (for Firefox ‘iMacros’ estension!) and catch the idea:

```
var ret = iimPlayCode("URL GOTO=http://www.mywebsite.com/test.php");
if (ret == 1)
    alert("Page is found!");
else
    alert("Page is not found!");
```

Comment: nice, but then what function do i need to use to tell imacros to switch to the next loop if "page is not found" so it can try over again with a different proxy? thanks !

Comment: If you have got a js-script for reading csv-file, you’ll see a loop over the line numbers. You just should continue this loop after the page has not been found. So, write: `else continue;` .